# Count Cells in Bright Field Images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have taken some bright field images with a microscope and I want to count the cells. This is the microscope image I have:
[Original Microscope Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSNNE.png)

What do you think, is this image fit for doing any kind of image processing?

This is how I did:

- The first thing I did was to crop the image so that the dark part on the left disappears.
- Then I applied a threshold to the image using **cv2.THRESH_TOZERO** to create a good contrast.The best value for the threshold turned out to be (**125**, 255).
- I realised that this was not good enough, so I thought of another strategy to use the white "aura" around the cells ie. contouring.
- Even here, I could not find a good value to outline the cells so that I can count them.

[Threshold (125, 255)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdIcD.png)
[Contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4WCw.png)

My question is which methods could I use to make this better and do you think, having the quality of the image in mind, that this is even possible?

The code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

# Load the image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread("My_Path", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Cropping the dark part of the image
cropped_image = img[0:1600, 350:1600]

# Display cropped image
cv2.imshow("Cropped Image", cropped_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow("Cropped Image")

# Compare to original
cv2.imshow("Original Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow("Original Image")

# Apply thresholding to the cropped image
th, img_thresh = cv2.threshold(cropped_image, 125, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)

# Display the thresholded image
cv2.imshow("Thresholded Image", img_thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
#-------------------#

#---  Method 2 - Contouring -------#
#Threshold Binary
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(cropped_image, 125, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('binary',thresh1)
cv2.waitKey(0)


#Detect contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

#Draw contours
img = cv2.drawContours(thresh1, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 1)
cv2.imshow('contours', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: have you tried adaptive thresholding instead of global thresholding?

Comment: Hello there, do you need to calculate the number of some certain kind of cells or all the cells?

Comment: @GáborFekete I did not know about the adaptive threshold - it works really well!

Comment: @MusabbirArrafi all the cells, all the cells in the image are of the same type